# Unable to combine date and time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to combine the following date and time columns to 1 date_time column:

```
casinghourly[['Date','Time']].head()
Out[275]: 
        Date     Time
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00
1 2014-01-01 01:00:00
2 2014-01-01 02:00:00
3 2014-01-01 03:00:00
4 2014-01-01 04:00:00
```

I've used the following code:

```
casinghourly.loc[:,'Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(casinghourly.Date.astype(str)+' '+casinghourly.Time.astype(str))
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

Fyi:

```
casinghourly[['Date','Time']].dtypes
Out[276]: 
Date     datetime64[ns]
Time    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Can somebody help me here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly concat `datetime64[ns]` with `timedelta64[ns]`:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date']+df['Time']

print(df['Date'])
0   2014-01-01 00:00:00
1   2014-01-01 01:00:00
2   2014-01-01 02:00:00
3   2014-01-01 03:00:00
4   2014-01-01 04:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print(df)
                 Date     Time
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00 00:00:00
1 2014-01-01 01:00:00 01:00:00
2 2014-01-01 02:00:00 02:00:00
3 2014-01-01 03:00:00 03:00:00
4 2014-01-01 04:00:00 04:00:00

print(df.dtypes)
Date     datetime64[ns]
Time    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```